# glDrawElements throws error code GL_INVALID_ENUM (0x500)

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I tried to draw a textured square using OpenGL and indexes. At first, I draw a simple white square using VAOs and VBOs. After that, I tried to create an index buffer object to draw the same simple white square but it doesn't draw anything and it throws error core `GL_INVALID_ENUM` (0x500). This error code is thrown after calling `glDrawElements`.

Here there are some parts of my code:

Function that creates Index Buffer Object, VAO, and VBO:

```
void Object::loadObject(const float *lpfVertices, size_t uVerticesSize, const char *lpbElementsList, size_t uNumElements) {
    this->uNumElements = uNumElements;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &uVertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(uVertexArrayID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uVertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uVertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uVerticesSize, (void *)lpfVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uElemetsListID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uElemetsListID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uNumElements, lpbElementsList, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Function that render my object:

```
void Object::renderObject() {
    glBindVertexArray(uVertexArrayID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, uElemetsListID);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, uNumElements, GL_BYTE, NULL);
}
```

Part of the main code:

```
object.loadObject(lpfTriangleVertices, sizeof(lpfTriangleVertices), lpbElementsList, sizeof(lpbElementsList));

uProgID = loadShader("default.vs", "default.fs");

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(lpstWndID)) {
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(uProgID);

    object.renderObject();

    glfwSwapBuffers(lpstWndID);
}
```

Comment: Add your error checking code more regularly, so you can identify the line of code causing the error. Once you identify the specific line, check its documentation to ensure the parameters you are passing are valid, this specific error means your passing a GL_ enum which it isn't expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, uNumElements, GL_BYTE, NULL);
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

`GL_BYTE` is not a valid argument for `type` in [`glDrawElements()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml):

> `type`
>
> Specifies the type of the values in `indices`. Must be one of                `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`.